# Xamarin.Forms.Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app. It works well, but keeps on crashing when the user brings it back from background after opening a few other apps. I'm new to Xamarin and I'm not sure how to debug this issue. This issue is not happening on iOS so far.

SplashActivity.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Util;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //  PersistableBundle persistentState
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); // persistentState
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            Task startupWork = new Task(() =>
                                        {
                                            Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
                                            Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
                                            Log.Debug(TAG, "Working in the background - important stuff.");
                                        });

            startupWork.ContinueWith(t =>
                                     {
                                         Log.Debug(TAG, "Work is finished - start Activity1.");
                                         StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
                                     }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            startupWork.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using HockeyApp.Android;
using HockeyApp.Android.Metrics;

using Xamarin.Android.Net; // Keep to make TLS 1.2 work

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "EventingVolunteers.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            // HockeyApp
            CrashManager.Register(this, Constants.HockeyAppID_Android);
            MetricsManager.Register(this, Application, Constants.HockeyAppID_Android);

            // Push Notifications
            RegisterForGCM();
        }

        private void RegisterForGCM()
        {
            string senders = Constants.GoogleConsoleProjectId;
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
            intent.SetPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
            intent.PutExtra("app", PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
            intent.PutExtra("sender", senders);
            StartService(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1.onFindViewById()Fragment.java:1933
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1057
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1252
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1234
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentManager.java:2046
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated()Fragment.java:1989
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1092
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1252
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1234
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentManager.java:2046
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentController.java:174
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart()FragmentActivity.java:598
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsAppCompatActivity.n_onStart(Native Method)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsAppCompatActivity.onStart()FormsAppCompatActivity.java:120
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart()Instrumentation.java:1260
android.app.Activity.performStart()Activity.java:6261
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2389
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2490
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()ActivityThread.java:1354
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:102
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:148
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5456
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:728
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:618
Xamarin caused by: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args)
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(string encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters)
Android.App.Activity.OnStart()
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnStart()
Android.App.Activity.n_OnStart(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:23d8bc20-60cf-4cac-a339-6cc6722e8667 (intptr,intptr)
--- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1.onFindViewById()Fragment.java:1933
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1057
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1252
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1234
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentManager.java:2046
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated()Fragment.java:1989
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1092
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1252
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1234
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentManager.java:2046
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentController.java:174
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart()FragmentActivity.java:598
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsAppCompatActivity.n_onStart(Native Method)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsAppCompatActivity.onStart()FormsAppCompatActivity.java:120
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart()Instrumentation.java:1260
android.app.Activity.performStart()Activity.java:6261
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2389
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2490
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()ActivityThread.java:1354
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:102
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:148
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5456
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:728
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:618
--- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1.onFindViewById()Fragment.java:1933
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1057
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1252
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1234
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentManager.java:2046
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated()Fragment.java:1989
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1092
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1252
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()FragmentManager.java:1234
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentManager.java:2046
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated()FragmentController.java:174
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart()FragmentActivity.java:598
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsAppCompatActivity.n_onStart(Native Method)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsAppCompatActivity.onStart()FormsAppCompatActivity.java:120
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart()Instrumentation.java:1260
android.app.Activity.performStart()Activity.java:6261
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2389
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity()ActivityThread.java:2490
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()ActivityThread.java:1354
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:102
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:148
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5456
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:728
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:618
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Amazon;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static string AppName { get { return "MyApp"; } }

        public static User User { get; set; }

        public static UserManager UserManager { get; private set; }

        public static VolunteerManager VolunteerManager { get; private set; }

        public static SignupManager SignupManager { get; private set; }

        static NavigationPage NavPage;

        public static bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get
            {
                if (User != null)
                    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(User.Email);
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
        {
            get
            {
                return new Action(() =>
                {
                    NavPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();

                    if (IsLoggedIn)
                    {
                        // Update RestService with new token
                        UserManager = new UserManager(new RestService());
                        VolunteerManager = new VolunteerManager(new RestService());
                        SignupManager = new SignupManager(new RestService());

                        NavPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new VolunteerDashboardPage(), NavPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
                        NavPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public static Action LogoutAction
        {
            get
            {
                return new Action(() =>
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<ICredentialsService>().DeleteCredentials();
                    App.User = null;
                    // NavPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    NavPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new LoginPage(), NavPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
                    NavPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                });
            }
        }

        public App()
        {
            User = new User();
            UserManager = new UserManager(new RestService());
            VolunteerManager = new VolunteerManager(new RestService());
            SignupManager = new SignupManager(new RestService());

            // AWS SDK
            var loggingConfig = AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig;
            loggingConfig.LogMetrics = true;
            loggingConfig.LogResponses = ResponseLoggingOption.Always;
            loggingConfig.LogMetricsFormat = LogMetricsFormatOption.JSON;
            loggingConfig.LogTo = LoggingOptions.SystemDiagnostics;

            //AWSConfigs.AWSRegion = "us-east-1";

            // Check if login needed
            if (DependencyService.Get<ICredentialsService>().DoCredentialsExist())
            {
                NavPage = new NavigationPage(new VolunteerDashboardPage());
                MainPage = NavPage;
                // MainPage = new VolunteerDashboardPage();
            } else {
                NavPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
                MainPage = NavPage;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work fine without the splash screen ?

Comment: Same issue when I remove SplashActivity.cs and make MainActivity.cs "MainLauncher = true".

Comment: So at least now we know it has nothing to do with the splash screen , It sayst that the crash is somwwhere in Android.App.Activity.OnStart() method. 
how does your equevilant app class in the xamarin.forms look like ?

Comment: I added the App.xaml.cs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint at OnStart() and at OnResume() and do the same scenario , which one hits ? the case should be that only is Resume. 
But from the trace it is OnStart that kicks . The problem would be if both get triggered then you probably have two instances of the same thing.

Comment: Here are 2 scenarios with different behaviors: First: open app, press home (circle) button, open another app, switch back to my app: OnResume called and everything is fine. Second: open app, press home (circle) button, open many other apps, debugger exits (I guess app gets closed), switch back to app = crash.

Comment: well then it is hard to know what is going on , maybe you do not have enough memory , so therefore  your app is closed ? place try catches and ShowAlerts everywhere to see where does it crash exactly. And also try to clean up the OnCreate() and make as it comes by default to see if makes a difference.

Comment: The pre release version of Xamarin.Forms lists a bug report with this error message. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.2.118-pre1).     However, bugzilla won't let see the details: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42075 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simular problem. I created app(Android) with Xamarin Forms 2.3.1.114.
I use Master-Detail page. After restore app I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view

I tryed Xamarin Forms 2.3.2.118-pre1. It is fixed this bug(42075),  but add new bugs(it is pre package). I installed Xamarin Forms 2.3.0.107(downgrade). It is work for me.  Hope this help for you.

Comment: I have same error, I am using xamarin forms 2.3.1.114. Do you know the root cause

Comment: Try Xamarin Forms 2.3.0.107(downgrade). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same error, does 2.3.2.127 stable fix this?

thanks

Comment: I have not tested the new version. I realized that the need to be updated very carefully. I use 2.3.0.107 now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding nuget package AndroidX.Fragment version "1.2.5.4" worked for me.
Able to reproduce only if i select developer options -> Don't keep activities

Answer (score 0):

This question is over 5 years old but this continues to be a problem in 2022 with Xamarin.Forms 5.x in a slightly different setup

I've got this happening quite a lot in a production app that was recently pushed to store. Replicating this issue manually in the real world is quite difficult from but sending the app to the background and executing:

```
adb shell "am kill <package-name>"
```

...and then tapping on the app from the launcher would immediately cause this crash.

My app references `Xamarin.AndroidX.Biometric` version `1.1.0.6` (the most latest as of March 2022) and this pulls in `Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment` version `1.3.6.3` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity` `1.3.1.2` as transitive dependencies.

Downgrading these 2 nugets by manually installing `Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment` version `1.2.54` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity` `1.2.2` resolves this according to comments on open issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14193.

The 'solution' is far from ideal so watch the linked github issue for more updates in the future.

Hope this helps someone having a similar setup